# How to load GraphDSL flow dynamically

Tags: akka-stream

I have requirements to load the `graph DSL` flow dynamically from  **DB** or **text file**. 
So instead of hard-coding the below flow ,loading the DSL from a store

in

```
~> f1 ~> bcast ~> f2 ~> merge ~> f3 ~> out
bcast ~> f4 ~> merge
```

Any ideas how to load  GraphDSL flow pro-grammatically ?

Comment: With the details provided, the answer can be anything in between "invent your own DSL" and "treat the DB or text file data as an additional Scala compilation unit". Also, any answer on that spectrum is likely a wrong solution to your actual problem.

Comment: How is this any different than compiling your code into a .class file and running your application with the class file in your classpath?